# How do you make a star rating as a visualisation

Tags: python, r, visualization

I have a simple dataframe.

```
name    Rating
George     2
Henry      4
```

In either python or R, I want to make a star rating visualization like in Amazon.

```
name     Rating
George     **
Henry      ****
```

Comment: I meant a visualization like this. http://www.emergingrnleader.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/Five-Stars.jpg

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In R:

```
df$Rating <- strrep("*", df$Rating)
```

Answer (score 4):

Python:

```
df.assign(Rating=df['Rating'].apply(lambda x: x * '*'))
```

Output:

```
     name Rating
0  George     **
1   Henry   ****
```